# Using form instead of div

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have login page. In which I am using form. It never worked. Later I tried div and it works fine. Can anyone tell me why it does not work with form.

Edit: I'm trying to login with firebase. While using form it gives an error.But while using div it logs me in.

```
<div class="login-clean" id="login_div">
  <form method="post">
    <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
    <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-navigate"></i></div>
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email_field" placeholder="Email"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password_field" placeholder="Password"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="login()" type="submit">Log In</button></div><a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot your email or password?</a>
  </form>
</div>

function login(){
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working / working?

Comment: Your form missing `action` attribute. If you are using JavaScript add your js code.

Comment: *Does not work* is not an explanation of what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but "it never worked" doesn't exactly help.  **What** hasn't worked?  **What** should it be doing? **What** is it doing that it shouldn't be doing?  Help us to help you!

Comment: If you copy your form to a clean file, you will see that after completing the inputs and press "Submit" it will reload the page as it should. So the form is working. Since you have a login() function within your onclick button, you should post here your js code. There is the problem.

Comment: @mhrabiee - action attribute is [not mandatory as of HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_action_attribute)... if it's missing, the form will submit to the same page

Comment: sorry guys. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submit button within a form is going to submit the form. So, after the `onclick` handler is triggered i.e. `login` is called. the page is refreshed with the form values submitted.

To prevent the button from submitting the form after logging in, change it to:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="login()" type="button">
```